# Cannot Move Files and Folders in the Jodit Pro editor with the Finder/FileBrowserPro

Tags: jodit

When using the Jodit (Pro) File Browser / Finder, you should be able to move files and folders around via drag and drop. The documentation on the backend indicates that the the following permissions should allow it (which is what is being sent):

```
"permissions": {
            "allowFolders": true,
            "allowImageCrop": true,
            "allowFileMove": true,
            "allowFolderMove": true,
            "allowFiles": true,
            "allowFolderRemove": true,
            "allowFileUpload": true,
            "allowFileRemove": true,
            "allowImageResize": true,
            "allowFileUploadRemote": true,
            "allowFolderCreate": true,
            "allowFileRename": true,
            "allowFolderRename": true
        }
```

However, when summoning the Finder/Filebrowser, you cannot Drag folders or files around to cause a move to occur. Drag seems to be disabled on those elements. The context menu also does not have a move option.

The following code (mostly copied from the xdsoft.net site) shows the behavior:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jodit.css"/>
<script src="jodit.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/finder/finder.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="editor"></div>
<form>
    <input type="text" readonly id="fileName" />
    <button onclick="openFb()" type="button">Select</button>
</form>
</body>

<script>
    Jodit.defaultOptions.license = 'REDACTED';
    Jodit.defaultOptions.language = 'en';
    const editor = new Jodit('#editor', {
        defaultFontSizePoints: 'pt',
        uploader: {
                url: 'https://xdsoft.net/jodit/finder/?action=fileUpload'
        },
        filebrowser: {
            ajax: {
                url: 'https://xdsoft.net/jodit/finder/'
            },
            height: 580
        },
        autofocus: true,
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Clicking on the Image button, then clicking on the browse option to launch the finder will show the finder dialog, but you cannot drag folders around.

Note: I am using the OEM version of Jodit (Pro)